# Fill in Column Based on Other Rows (R)

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, if-statement

I am looking for a way to fill in a column in R based on values in a different column. Below is what my data looks like.

| year | action | player | end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2001 | 1 | Mike | 2003 |
| 2002 | 0 | Mike | NA |
| 2003 | 0 | Mike | NA |
| 2004 | 0 | Mike | NA |
| 2001 | 0 | Alan | NA |
| 2002 | 0 | Alan | NA |
| 2003 | 1 | Alan | 2004 |
| 2004 | 0 | Alan | NA |

I would like to either change the "action" column or create a new column such that it reflects the duration between the "year" and "end" variables. Below is what it would look like:

| year | action | player | end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2001 | 1 | Mike | 2003 |
| 2002 | 1 | Mike | NA |
| 2003 | 1 | Mike | NA |
| 2004 | 0 | Mike | NA |
| 2001 | 0 | Alan | NA |
| 2002 | 0 | Alan | NA |
| 2003 | 1 | Alan | 2004 |
| 2004 | 1 | Alan | NA |

I have tried to do this with the following loop:

```
i <- 0 
z <- 0 
for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
  i <- z + i + 1
  if (df[i, 2] == 0) {}
  else {df[i, 5] = (df[i, 4] -  df[i, 1])}
z <- df[i,5]
for (z in i:nrow(df)){df[i, 2] = 1}
  }
```

Here, my i value is skyrocketing, breaking the loop. I am not sure why that is occuring. I'd be interested to either know how to fix my approach or how to do this in a smarter fashion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need for explicit loops here.

First group your data frame by `player`. Then find the rows where the cumulative sum (`cumsum`) of `action` is greater than 0 and the `year` is less than or equal to the `end` year of the group. If the row meets these conditions, set `action` to 1, otherwise to 0.

Using the dplyr package you could achieve this in a couple of lines:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(player) %>%
  mutate(action = as.numeric(cumsum(action) > 0 & year <= na.omit(end)[1]))
#> # A tibble: 8 x 4
#> # Groups:   player [2]
#>    year action player   end
#>   <int>  <dbl> <chr>  <int>
#> 1  2001      1 Mike    2003
#> 2  2002      1 Mike      NA
#> 3  2003      1 Mike      NA
#> 4  2004      0 Mike      NA
#> 5  2001      0 Alan      NA
#> 6  2002      0 Alan      NA
#> 7  2003      1 Alan    2004
#> 8  2004      1 Alan      NA
```